# Why my DateTask code block does not work?

Tags: swift

I create a request to the server, and in the end I expect to receive data, which I then transform into a model using a function, for this I created a session

```
func fetchNewsData(forCoutry country: String, category: String, complition: @escaping (NewsDataModel) -> ()) {
        
    let urlString = "some url string"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) {  data, response, error in
        print ("ERROR: \(error)")
        guard let data = data else { return }
        guard let newsData = self.parseJSON(withData: data) else { return }
        complition(newsData)
    }
        
    task.resume()
}
```

but the following code just doesn't work

```
print ("ERROR: \(error)")
guard let data = data else { return }
guard let newsData = self.parseJSON(withData: data) else { return }
complition(newsData)
```

I used breakpoints to find out until what point everything is going well, and I realized that this particular block of code is not working.

when I set a breakpoint between the `let session` and the `let task`, the code stopped there, but when I set my code to an `print(error)`, this breakpoint did not work

I used the function `fetchNewsData` in `viewDidLoad` and I want to work to fill the array with elements that I expect to receive from the data that will come on this request, but my array does not receive any elements, and it remains empty, because of this my application does not work

why part of the code doesn't work, and how can I get the data I need from it?

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint on the previous guard statement. Maybe the url is not good and it stops there. Are you sure the string you are providing is a good URL?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that the URL is formed correctly, there are no problems here, because after the guard block I used the print(url), and I was getting a response in the console

Comment: Did you try the printed url in a browser?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: All your variables (session, task) are local (to the function). It could be that once function exits, both session and task are simply deallocated and thus task is not running. As a trial, try to move them to class level and see if it helps. If it does, look at your app's architecture and see how to preserve it properly then (e.g. should your function return the task, should session be shared etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a poor understanding of closures
I was not calling my method correctly to get the data. Having figured it out, I realized that the problem is precisely in a different approach when calling this method